# Totaling values in array and grouping by new index

Tags: php

I have an array (shown below) that is currently indexed by employee and so it gives me a starting key of an employee and then their totals of sales/downloads by department (1654, 1675)

What I'm trying to do is loop through this and only key this new array up by the department. I have several categories but I'm only showing Tickets for simplicity. I'd like to index by department and loop to add all of the totals within so that I end up with only two main levels, so even if I have 30 employees I still only show the two levels for 1654 and 1675 but it totals all categories as they are already shown. I want to keep the format the same, just add the totals together for each index

My issue is that I'm a little lost in my looping and where/how to iterate it properly.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
    $data =[
        'Employee1' => [
            "1654" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    "Tickets" => [
                       'saved' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 210,
                            'old_goal' => 200,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'downloaded' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 100,
                            'old_goal' => 40,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'overflow' => 145,
                        'projDownload' => 45,
                        'saved_percent' => 25,
                        'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                    ],
                ],
                "total" => [
                   'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "1675" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    "Tickets" => [
                       'saved' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 210,
                            'old_goal' => 200,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'downloaded' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 100,
                            'old_goal' => 40,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'overflow' => 145,
                        'projDownload' => 45,
                        'saved_percent' => 25,
                        'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                    ],
                ],
                "total" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ]
        ],
    'employee2' => [
            "1654" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    "Tickets" => [
                       'saved' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 210,
                            'old_goal' => 200,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'downloaded' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 100,
                            'old_goal' => 40,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'overflow' => 145,
                        'projDownload' => 45,
                        'saved_percent' => 25,
                        'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                    ],
                ],
                "total" => [
                   'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "1675" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    "Tickets" => [
                       'saved' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 210,
                            'old_goal' => 200,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'downloaded' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 100,
                            'old_goal' => 40,
                            'now' => 100,
                            'comparison' => 200
                        ],
                        'overflow' => 145,
                        'projDownload' => 45,
                        'saved_percent' => 25,
                        'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                    ],
                ],
                "total" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($data as $userName => $emps) {
        foreach ($emps as $empIndex => $category) {
            if (!array_key_exists($empIndex, $finalResults)) {
                $finalResults[$empIndex] = [
                    'total' => [
                        'saved' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 0,
                            'old_goal' => 0,
                            'now' => 0,
                            'week_last_yaer' => 0
                        ],
                        'downloaded' => [
                            'up_to_date' => 0,
                            'old_goal' => 0,
                            'now' => 0,
                            'week_last_yaer' => 0
                        ],
                        'overflow' => 0,
                        'saved_percent' => 0,
                        'downloaded_percent' => 0,
                        'projDownload' => 0,
                    ]
                ];
            }
            foreach ($category as $catIndex => $categoryDetails) {
                foreach( $categoryDetails as $totals => $catTotals){
                    if (!array_key_exists($catIndex, $finalResults[$empIndex])) {
                    $finalResults[$empIndex][$catIndex] = [];
                    }
                    if ($catIndex !== 'total') {
                        foreach ($categoryDetails as $productCode => $productData) {
                            if (!array_key_exists($productCode, $finalResults[$empIndex][$catIndex])) {
                                $finalResults[$empIndex][$catIndex][$productCode] = [
                                   
                                ];
                            }
                            //iterate and add
                        }
                    } else {
                        //iterate and add
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    print_r($finalResults);
    ?>
```

UPDATE:

desired outcome:

```
"1654" => [
    "Tickets" => [
        "Tickets" => [
           'saved' => [
                'up_to_date' => 420,
                'old_goal' => 400,
                'now' => 200,
                'comparison' => 400
            ],
            'downloaded' => [
                'up_to_date' => 200,
                'old_goal' => 80,
                'now' => 200,
                'comparison' => 400
            ],
            'overflow' => 290,
            'projDownload' => 90,
            'saved_percent' => 50,
            'downloaded_percent' => 28,
        ],
    ],
    "total" => [
       'saved' => [
            'up_to_date' => 420,
            'old_goal' => 400,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'downloaded' => [
            'up_to_date' => 200,
            'old_goal' => 80,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'overflow' => 290,
        'projDownload' => 90,
        'saved_percent' => 50,
        'downloaded_percent' => 28,
    ],
],
"1675" => [
    "Tickets" => [
        "Tickets" => [
           'saved' => [
            'up_to_date' => 420,
            'old_goal' => 400,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'downloaded' => [
            'up_to_date' => 200,
            'old_goal' => 80,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'overflow' => 290,
        'projDownload' => 90,
        'saved_percent' => 50,
        'downloaded_percent' => 28,
        ],
    ],
    "total" => [
        'saved' => [
            'up_to_date' => 420,
            'old_goal' => 400,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'downloaded' => [
            'up_to_date' => 200,
            'old_goal' => 80,
            'now' => 200,
            'comparison' => 400
        ],
        'overflow' => 290,
        'projDownload' => 90,
        'saved_percent' => 50,
        'downloaded_percent' => 28,
    ],
],
"total" => [
    "Tickets" => [
        "Tickets" => [
           'saved' => [
                'up_to_date' => 840,
                'old_goal' => 800,
                'now' => 400,
                'comparison' => 800
            ],
            'downloaded' => [
                'up_to_date' => 400,
                'old_goal' => 160,
                'now' => 400,
                'comparison' => 800
            ],
            'overflow' => 580,
            'projDownload' => 180,
            'saved_percent' => 100,
            'downloaded_percent' => 56,
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: Could you please add a desired outcome so the question is easier to understand?

Comment: @0stone0 yes I will add one now, sorry

Comment: @0stone0 I added it now, basically just a single array grouped by department that totals everything into the same previous structure

Comment: @0stone0 let me know if that looks right and makes sense

Comment: I still find it hard to see the real question, how to group the data. Even tho some people have already answer the question, adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with dummy data, could simply the question and will increase the change of a *good* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think this produces your desired output.

```
function thing($addTo, $new){
    
    if (is_array($new)){
        foreach($new as $k => $v){
            if (is_array($v)){
                $addTo[$k] = thing($addTo[$k], $v);
            }else{
                $addTo[$k] += $v;
            }
            
        }
    }else{
        $addTo += $new;
    }
    
    return $addTo;
}




$newArray = [];

foreach ($data as $employee) {
    foreach($employee as $deptName => $dept){
        
        // Department doesn't exist, add it to array
        if (!array_key_exists($deptName, $newArray)) {
            $newArray[$deptName] = $dept;
        }else{ // Department exist already, combine them
            
            $newArray[$deptName] = thing($newArray[$deptName], $dept);
        }
    }
}
        

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this using recursive way

let say you have data like this

```php
$data =[
    'Employee1' => [
        "1654" => [
            "Tickets" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'saved' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 210,
                    'old_goal' => 200,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'downloaded' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 100,
                    'old_goal' => 40,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'overflow' => 145,
                'projDownload' => 45,
                'saved_percent' => 25,
                'downloaded_percent' => 14,
            ],
        ],
        "1675" => [
            "Tickets" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'saved' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 210,
                    'old_goal' => 200,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'downloaded' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 100,
                    'old_goal' => 40,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'overflow' => 145,
                'projDownload' => 45,
                'saved_percent' => 25,
                'downloaded_percent' => 14,
            ],
        ]
    ],
'employee2' => [
        "1654" => [
            "Tickets" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'saved' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 210,
                    'old_goal' => 200,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'downloaded' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 100,
                    'old_goal' => 40,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'overflow' => 145,
                'projDownload' => 45,
                'saved_percent' => 25,
                'downloaded_percent' => 14,
            ],
        ],
        "1675" => [
            "Tickets" => [
                "Tickets" => [
                    'saved' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 210,
                        'old_goal' => 200,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'downloaded' => [
                        'up_to_date' => 100,
                        'old_goal' => 40,
                        'now' => 100,
                        'comparison' => 200
                    ],
                    'overflow' => 145,
                    'projDownload' => 45,
                    'saved_percent' => 25,
                    'downloaded_percent' => 14,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'saved' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 210,
                    'old_goal' => 200,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'downloaded' => [
                    'up_to_date' => 100,
                    'old_goal' => 40,
                    'now' => 100,
                    'comparison' => 200
                ],
                'overflow' => 145,
                'projDownload' => 45,
                'saved_percent' => 25,
                'downloaded_percent' => 14,
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

first we need to define the sum function for 2 unkown array

```php
function sum_value($array1, $array2) {
    $result = [];
    // sum array1 and array2
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        // check if $key exists in array2
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
            // if the value is integer, than sum them
            if(is_int($value)) {
                $result[$key] = $value + $array2[$key];
            } else {
                $result[$key] = sum_value($value, $array2[$key]);
            }
            // remove $key from array2
            unset($array2[$key]);
        } else {
            // add key to result
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    // add the rest of array2 if exists
    foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

then we can sum the value like this

```php
// create array to store all the departments
$departments = [];
// loop through all the employee
foreach($data as $key => $employee) {
    // loop through every department
    foreach($employee as $department => $info) {
        if(!array_key_exists($department, $departments)) {
            $departments[$department] = $info; // just set the value if this is the first value in the department
        } else {
            $departments[$department] = sum_value($departments[$department], $info); // else add them
        }
    }
}
```

finally you get the output on the `$departments` variable, the output look like this

```json
{
  "1654": {
    "Tickets": {
      "Tickets": {
        "saved": {
          "up_to_date": 420,
          "old_goal": 400,
          "now": 200,
          "comparison": 400
        },
        "downloaded": {
          "up_to_date": 200,
          "old_goal": 80,
          "now": 200,
          "comparison": 400
        },
        "overflow": 290,
        "projDownload": 90,
        "saved_percent": 50,
        "downloaded_percent": 28
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "saved": {
        "up_to_date": 420,
        "old_goal": 400,
        "now": 200,
        "comparison": 400
      },
      "downloaded": {
        "up_to_date": 200,
        "old_goal": 80,
        "now": 200,
        "comparison": 400
      },
      "overflow": 290,
      "projDownload": 90,
      "saved_percent": 50,
      "downloaded_percent": 28
    }
  },
  "1675": {
    "Tickets": {
      "Tickets": {
        "saved": {
          "up_to_date": 420,
          "old_goal": 400,
          "now": 200,
          "comparison": 400
        },
        "downloaded": {
          "up_to_date": 200,
          "old_goal": 80,
          "now": 200,
          "comparison": 400
        },
        "overflow": 290,
        "projDownload": 90,
        "saved_percent": 50,
        "downloaded_percent": 28
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "saved": {
        "up_to_date": 420,
        "old_goal": 400,
        "now": 200,
        "comparison": 400
      },
      "downloaded": {
        "up_to_date": 200,
        "old_goal": 80,
        "now": 200,
        "comparison": 400
      },
      "overflow": 290,
      "projDownload": 90,
      "saved_percent": 50,
      "downloaded_percent": 28
    }
  }
}
```